# Google Sheets if and ifs statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a range of results data between 1-9 , which I want to convert to a grade.

```
=IFS(I2<2,"2B",I2<3,"2P",I2<4,"2A",I2<5,"3B",I2<6,"3P",I2<7,"3A",I2<8,"4B",I2<9,"4P",I2<10,"4A",I2<11,"5B")
```

The problem I have is how to include a grade when the number is a decimal. Above the .4 the grade stays down, above .4 it goes up.
Foe example 6.4 ="3A", 6.6="4B"

Comment: Your post details are not clear. You say *both* that the grade stays down *and* goes up "above .4". I *think* you mean that a decimal amount up to .4 rounds down and above .4 rounds up. But even then, it's also not clear what should happen at, say, 4.1 or 4.05 (round down or round up)? Are you trying to do this for just *one row* (Row 2) or for many rows?

Comment: Thanks Eric. 4.1-4.4 rounds down. 4.5+ rounds up. There are 30 rows.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Will there ever be occasions of something like 4.43? And what is the *lowest* possible score? 0? 1? Also, see player0's response below. If that works for you, then you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFS(I2<2.5, "2B", I2<3.5, "2P", I2<4.5, "2A", I2<5.5, "3B", I2<6.5, "3P", 
     I2<7.5, "3A", I2<8.5, "4B", I2<9.5, "4P", I2<10.5, "4A", I2<11.5, "5B")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve the problem of a different grade for data between the values. What I need is =IFS(I2=1.0-1.5 "2B", I2=1.6=1.9,"2P" and so on.

Comment: 5  4.5  6 3.8 4.83 3B  Where 4.83 is the average. 4.83 is closer to 5 which should be "3P" Code is: =IFS(I8<2.5,"2B",I8<3.5,"2P",I8<4.5,"2A",I8<5.5,"3B",I8<6.5,"3P",I8<7.5,"3A",I8<8.5,"4B",I8<9.5,"4P",I8<10.5,"4A",I8<11.5,"5B")

Comment: @StephenJulieDoyle share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can try round function.

```
=IFS(round(I2)<2,"2B",round(I2)<3,"2P",round(I2)<4,"2A",round(I2)<5,"3B",round(I2)<6,"3P",round(I2)<7,"3A",round(I2)<8,"4B",round(I2)<9,"4P",round(I2)<10,"4A",round(I2)<11,"5B")
```